# How can I add a counter for when I click a button, so I can use it to know what file line to write to?

Tags: java, swing

I am very new to Java, but I'm using it for a school project to make a student tracker. I'm just starting with the layout, and am adding students to a file right now. On line 138, I need a way to add a counter every time I click the add button.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File StudentNames = new File("StudentNames.txt");
        File StudentGrades = new File("StudentGrades.txt");
        File StudentScore = new File("StudentScore.txt");

        FileWriter NameFileWriter = new FileWriter("StudentNames.txt");
        FileWriter GradeFileWriter = new FileWriter("StudentGrades.txt");
        FileWriter ScoreFileWriter = new FileWriter("StudentScore.txt");

        FileReader NameFileReader = new FileReader(StudentNames);
        FileReader GradeFileReader = new FileReader(StudentGrades);
        FileReader ScoreFileReader = new FileReader(StudentScore);

        String[] NamesString = new String[] {""};
        List<String> NamesList = Arrays.asList(NamesString);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tyke Tracking");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Adding a panel to center the buttons
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Center = new GridBagConstraints();

        Center.gridx = 0;
        JButton StudentsButton = new JButton("Students");
        panel.add(StudentsButton, Center);

        Center.gridx = 1;
        JButton PrizesButton = new JButton("Prizes");
        panel.add(PrizesButton, Center);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Student Section
        JFrame StuFrame = new JFrame("Tyke Tracking Students");
        StuFrame.setSize(500,500);
        StuFrame.setResizable(false);
        StuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel StuPanelLeft = new JPanel();

        JTextArea StudentsListed = new JTextArea();
        StudentsListed.setEditable(false);
        StudentsListed.setPreferredSize((new Dimension(250,500)));
        StuPanelLeft.add(StudentsListed);

        JPanel StuPanelRight = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints StuRight = new GridBagConstraints();

        StuRight.gridy = 0;
        JButton AddStu = new JButton("Add Students");
        StuPanelRight.add(AddStu, StuRight);

        StuRight.gridy = 1;
        JButton EditStu = new JButton("Edit Students");
        StuPanelRight.add(EditStu, StuRight);

        StuRight.gridy = 2;
        JButton Report = new JButton("Get Report");
        Report.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,23)); //Making it even to other buttons
        StuPanelRight.add(Report, StuRight);

        StuRight.gridy = 3;
        JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,23));
        StuPanelRight.add(backButton, StuRight);

        StuFrame.getContentPane().add(StuPanelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
        StuFrame.getContentPane().add(StuPanelRight);

        //Adding Students
        JFrame Adding = new JFrame("Adding Students");
        Adding.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        Adding.setSize(200,150);
        Adding.setResizable(false);

        JPanel AddStuPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel AddStuPanelTop = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints AddStuGBC = new GridBagConstraints();

        AddStuGBC.gridy = 1;
        AddStuGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JTextField addNameField = new JTextField();
        addNameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));
        AddStuPanelTop.add(addNameField, AddStuGBC);

        AddStuGBC.gridy = 0;
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        AddStuPanelTop.add(nameLabel, AddStuGBC);

        AddStuGBC.gridy = 2;
        JLabel gradeLabel = new JLabel("Grade %:");
        AddStuPanelTop.add(gradeLabel, AddStuGBC);

        AddStuGBC.gridy = 3;
        JTextField addGradeField = new JTextField();
        addGradeField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));
        AddStuPanelTop.add(addGradeField, AddStuGBC);

        AddStuGBC.gridy = 4;
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        AddStuPanel.add(addButton, AddStuGBC);

        AddStuGBC.gridx = 1;
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        AddStuPanel.add(closeButton, AddStuGBC);

        Adding.getContentPane().add(AddStuPanelTop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Adding.getContentPane().add(AddStuPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Adding.setVisible(false);

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    NameFileWriter.append(addNameField.getText());
                    NameFileWriter.close();}
                catch (IOException ignored) {}
                try {
                    GradeFileWriter.append(addGradeField.getText());
                    GradeFileWriter.close();}
                catch (IOException ignored) {}
                //Way to count how many students there are, to write to correct line in files
                }
        });

        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Adding.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        StudentsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                StuFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                StuFrame.setVisible(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        AddStu.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Adding.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

I tried to name a variable and use a++, but I can't use it and keep adding since it's accessed within an inner variable. If I initiated it inside, then it would initiate it back every time i clicked the button.

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an uppercase character. Some variable are correct, others are not. Be consistent. 2) An application should only have a single main JFrame. Other child window can be a JDialog. 3) All your code should NOT be contained in the main() method. 4) If you want a counter, then you need an instance variable for your class. This is why all the code should not be in the main method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578405/how-do-i-make-my-for-loop-delay-for-1-second-between-iterations-on-jframe/67578463#67578463 for a better structured simple example.

Comment: You can also read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics and plenty of working examples with better structured code.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, Swing is single threaded so thread safety is not a concern with this solution. Nonetheless, using an `AtomicInteger` here is still an effective way of maintaining the click count from this anonymous class. A class member in the containing class would be a better solution but this is executed from a static context so I hesitate to suggest that.

```java
      AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

      addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
               NameFileWriter.append(addNameField.getText());
               NameFileWriter.close();}
            catch (IOException ignored) {}
            try {
               GradeFileWriter.append(addGradeField.getText());
               GradeFileWriter.close();}
            catch (IOException ignored) {}
            // Way to count how many students there are, to write to correct line in files
            // Every time this statement is called, one is added
            // to the total and the total is returned
            int totalClicks = atomicInteger.addAndGet(1);
         }
      });
```

Comment: Swing is single threaded. All code executed in the ActionListener is executed on the Event dispatch Thread. There is no need for an AtomicInteger.

Comment: please don't replicate the naming violations of the question in your answer